# Youtube media thumbnail size

Tags: 8, media

I want to control the thumbnail image size for my media entities of type video.

The thumbnail image size being fetched by the media module from Youtube has 480 x 360px.

I want to use the 1280x720 images. Is there a way for me to control this?

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: Drupal's core media module.

Comment: This takes core patching. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal core issue regarding this problem:  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3042423

After patching, I would implement the new hook_oembed_resource_data_alter:

```
function MY_MODULE_oembed_resource_data_alter(array &$data, $url) {
  if (strpos($url, 'youtube.com/oembed') !== FALSE) {
    $thumbnailUrl = str_replace('hqdefault', 'maxresdefault', $data['thumbnail_url']);
    $data['thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnailUrl;
  }
}
```

Then I would also run an update hook to update the existing thumbnails:

```
function MY_MODULE_update_N(&$sandbox) {
  /** @var \Drupal\media\MediaStorage $mediaStorage */
  $mediaStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media');
  if (!isset($sandbox['progress'])) {
    $result = $mediaStorage->getQuery()->condition('bundle', 'video');
    $mediaItems = $result->execute();
    $max = count($mediaItems) - 1;
    $sandbox['progress'] = 0;
    $sandbox['mediaItems'] = array_values($mediaItems);
    $sandbox['max'] = $max;
  }
  $progress = $sandbox['progress'];
  /** @var \Drupal\media\MediaInterface $media */
  $media = $mediaStorage->load($sandbox['mediaItems'][$progress]);
  if (!$media->get('thumbnail')->isEmpty()) {
    $media->get('thumbnail')->delete();
  }
  $media->updateQueuedThumbnail();
  $media->save();
  $sandbox['progress']++;
  $sandbox['#finished'] = empty($sandbox['max']) ? 1 : $sandbox['progress'] / $sandbox['max'];
}
```

Comment: While this approach works nicely, it has one major drawback. Your code in `MY_MODULE_oembed_resource_data_alter` forces all thumbnails to be obtained in `maxresdefault` quality. However, the reality is that not all videos from youtube have thumbnails available in this format. When a remote video is created which doesn't have a high quality thumbnail, no thumb is generated at all (although lower quality thumbnails do exist). I worked around this limitation by grabbing the hightest available, to choose from:  'maxresdefault', 'sddefault', 'hqdefault', 'mqdefault', 'default'.

Answer (score 2):

Building on José Trindade's answer, here's my solution that uses Guzzle to find the highest resolution that YouTube actually provides for a given video:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

/**
 * Implements hook_oembed_resource_data_alter().
 *
 * This tries to fetch the highest available YouTube video thumbnail by sending
 * requests via Guzzle for the various formats from highest to lowest, using the
 * first one that doesn't return a 404.
 *
 * @param array &$data
 *   The oEmbed data, parsed into an array.
 *
 * @param string $url
 *   The oEmbed URL that $data was retrieved from.
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3042423
 *   This hook won't be invoked unless this Drupal core patch is applied.
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_oembed_resource_data_alter(array &$data, $url) {
  if (
    $data['provider_name'] === 'YouTube' &&
    strpos($data['thumbnail_url'], 'hqdefault.jpg') !== false
  ) {
    // Array of thumbnail sizes above 'hqdefault' to try, started with the
    // largest size.
    //
    // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542029
    $thumbnailTypes = [
      'maxresdefault' => [
        'width'   => 1920,
        'height'  => 1080,
      ],
      'sddefault' => [
        'width'   => 640,
        'height'  => 480,
      ],
    ];

    $client = new GuzzleClient();

    foreach ($thumbnailTypes as $thumbnailName => $thumbnailDimensions) {
      // Replace 'hqdefault' in the thumbnail URL with the current type we're
      // testing for.
      $testThumbnailURL = str_replace(
        'hqdefault',
        $thumbnailName,
        $data['thumbnail_url']
      );

      // We need to wrap the request in a try {} catch {} because Guzzle will
      // throw an exception on a 404.
      try {
        $response = $client->request('GET', $testThumbnailURL);

      // Got an exception? Skip to the next thumbnail size, assuming this
      // returned a 404 or ran into some other error.
      } catch (Exception $exception) {
        continue;
      }

      // If this was a 200 response, update the thumbnail URL and dimensions
      // with the higher resolution and break out of the loop.
      if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
        $data['thumbnail_url']    = $testThumbnailURL;
        $data['thumbnail_width']  = $thumbnailDimensions['width'];
        $data['thumbnail_height'] = $thumbnailDimensions['height'];

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to replace `YOUR_MODULE` with the name of your custom module.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The `maxresdefault` isn't always fullHD, so I would recommend using `getimagesize()` to test for the dimensions of the image returned by Guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jose Trinidad and Ambient.Impact for their answers, they helped me a lot. To get the Jose's update-function to work in my project though I had to set the bundle to 'remote_video' instead of only video:

`$result = $mediaStorage->getQuery()->condition('bundle', 'remote_video');`

I think the video bundle refers to normally uploaded videos